# Hide and show SVG in react with useState no functioning

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a pretty simple use case in which im trying to swap out the 2 svgs im using in react by adding and removing a classes called `visible` and `invisible`. They are both `visibility: visibile` but one has `opacity: 0` and the other `opacity: 1`. The hamburger icon should show, then when clicked, the close icon should show and the hamburger should fade. I had it working at some point, then i made a change and broke it. and for the life of me, i cant fix it. Interestingly, in my app, the one icon shows, you click it, and they both dissapear. In the sandbox, they both stay visibile..

[I have made this sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-sinoussi-1kxz9?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Can you check your sandbox link again? It doesn't seem to contain your example code.

Comment: seems to work for me @JureC.